# Adobe Creative Cloud Desktop Window Opens Automatically on Startup

Tags: adobe-creative-cloud

Starting with latest update for Adobe Creative Cloud Desktop, every time I boot up, the Creative Cloud Desktop window opens automatically. I want the Creative Cloud Desktop program to launch on system startup, but I do not want the window to open each time I boot up. Why does this happen, and how can I stop it?

I have asked for assistance on the Adobe Forums, but the only advice that I am receiving is to remove it from the list of Windows startup programs. This of course will stop Creative Cloud from launching altogether, but I want it to launch, I just do not want the Creative Cloud window to pop up each time I boot up.

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro x64 and Adobe Creative Cloud Desktop v2.1. As of this post, it is the latest release of Creative Cloud.

Comment: It keeps on popping up after a network disconnection as well, which is very irritating.

Comment: @paradroid Yes, I have noticed that this is an issue as well.

Comment: @paradroid The latest release of Creative Cloud fixes the issue I posted about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of other people have responded to my post on the Adobe Forums about this issue claiming to have the same problem. Based on this, I believe it is safe to say that this is an issue with the Adobe Creative Cloud Desktop v2.1.0.108 release. For now, it looks like the only option available to anyone with this problem is to wait until Adobe fixes it with another update.

**Adobe appears to have resolved this issue as of the release of Creative Cloud Desktop 2.1.2.114.**

Answer (score 0):

I founded how to stop 'Automatic Startup' of Adobe Creative Cloud, the actual subject that cause this problem is AdobeIPCBroker.exe feature that have an XML document in the AdobeIPCBroker.exe main folder called StartupOptions , locate it in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\IPC... Cut the StartupOptions.XML document into Desktop and right-click and go under 'Edit' and find where is the first `<vcint>5</vcint>` and modify the value to 0... then find the second one `<vcint>1</vcint>` and modify the value to 0, after all this u need to cut/copy the XML document back to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\OOBE\PDApp\IPC... RESTART and your welcome if worked for you too

Comment: Were you having this problem recently then?

Answer (score 0):

I have Illustrator installed in a Terminal Server and all users were getting the annoying Creative Cloud popup after every login. I tried editing the StartupOptions.XML as suggested above but it didn't work, I would get a Windows error message instead.

I ended up changing the security permissions for file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Creative Cloud\ACC\Creative Cloud.exe" and only giving read/execute access to those users that needed to use Illustrator. That solved my problem.